# Something from string in list python

Tags: python, list

I have a list with keywords id = ['pop','ppp','cre'] and now I am going through a bunch of files/large strings and if any of these keywords are in these files than I have to be able to do something...

like:

```
id = ['pop','ppp','cre']
if id in dataset:
         print id
```

But i think now all of these 3 or later maybe more have to be in the dataset and not just only one.

Comment: Do you want to match any of the keywords in `id`, or all of the keywords in `id`?

Comment: @Jasper: You shouldn't use `id` as a variable name, since it shadows the builtin function `id()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `all` to make sure all the values in your `id` list are in the dataset:

```
id = ['pop', 'ppp', 'cre']
if all(i in dataset for i in id):
    print id
```

Comment: The question specifies that any, not all, should be in the dataset

Comment: "But i think now all of these 3 or later maybe more have to be in the dataset and not just only one."

Comment: "if any of these keywords are in these files than I have to be able to do something". I think that quote refers to what he believes his current code is doing.

Comment: ... yes, which is in fact the problem that needs solving.

Comment: I'll ask him to clarify. We are clearly understanding his problem statement differently.

Answer (score 1):

Your code as it stands will actually look through `dataset` for the entire list "`['pop', 'ppp', 'cre']`". Why don't you try something like this:

```
for item in id:
    if item in dataset:
        print id
```

**Edit:**

This will probably be more efficient:

```
for item in dataset:
    if item in id:
        print id
```

Assuming |dataset| > |id| and you break out of the loop when you find a match.

Comment: He says dataset is a bunch of files/large strings. I'm not sure that iterating over it will be helpful.

Comment: Look at the documentation for `all()`: http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=any#all , that's exactly what the function does. How would you propose to check if an element is in `dataset` without iterating over it?

Comment: Iterating over a string returns the values one character at a time. So no, that's not going to work.

Comment: Its iterating over a "bunch of files/large strings", as you said, not a string.

Comment: OK, so if it's a list of strings how is that better? You're checking if the whole large string is in `id`?

Comment: The edited version? Its not always going to be better, either way it is `O(n*m)`, (n=|dataset|, m=|id|), however, I think in the average case it will be better, as instead of making a number of long passes through dataset, you make a larger number of small passes through id. However, honestly, I'm not sure, and in the worst case its the same.Artsiom probably has the best answer in any case (assuming we are the ones interpreting the question correctly)

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned that you need to check any word within dataset then I think [any() built-in method will help](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=any#any):

```
if any(word in dataset for word in id):
    # do something
```

Or:

```
if [word for word in id if word in dataset]:
    # do something
```

And:

```
if filter(lambda word: word in dataset, id):
    # do something
```